# How do I use the $name parameter in Kotlin using composable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to use a string resource with composable functions, I adjusted my code, but it tells me that I have an unused parameter - name("Zero")

```
 string name="greeting">Hello, my name is $name</string>

 //this one works fine but I don't want to use this one --
 string name="greeting1">Hello, my name is %1$s</string>


@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
Surface(color = Color.Green, border = BorderStroke(1.dp, color = Color.Cyan)) {
    //Text(text = "Hello, my name is $name!", modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp))
    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.greeting1,"Zero"))
}
```

}

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
GreetingCardTheme {
    Greeting("Zero")
}
```

}

Comment: well, what I have works. did you read the full post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

> Parameter 'name' is never used

because you have a parameter declared in your composable `"name"` and you are not using it since you have a fixed string `"Zero"`.

```
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    //...You are not using name   
    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.greeting1,"Zero"))
}
```

Instead use:

```
Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.greeting1,name))
```

In any case in `strings.xml` you can also use:

```
<string name="greeting">Hello, my name is</string>
```

and in your composable:

```
Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.greeting) +" $name")
```